# Random numbers -200 to 700? (In C)

Tags: c, random, numbers

```
randomNums[i] = rand() % (0 + 11);
```

produces numbers between 0 and 10, but how do I make the range to include negative numbers, -200 to 700?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`randomNums[i] = rand() % 901 - 200`